# Can my contract get on top with flattening instead of the imports?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I use hardhat to flatten my contract which has 2 imports (ERC721 and Ownable). The flattened contract is for verification on Etherscan (actually Croscan) and for users to read the contract. Now my 'own' contract is at the very bottom of the flattened contract including my remarks, which I want to have (both) at the top. Is that possible in some way?